# Change number of columns in gridview with animation ( item to item )

Tags: android, animation, gridview, scroll

I want to create a animation in android with Gridview. The animation will be when I will change the number of columns from 2 to 4.

I used the following line to change the number of columns:

```
If (true)
    gridView.setNumColumns(2);
Else 
    gridView.setNumColumns(4);
```

I want to achieve animation like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NkuChdWA_I
```

Answer (score 0):

I need it too and then i created the following class:

```
/**
* Created by Butzke on 19/05/2017.
*/

public class GridViewAnimated extends GridView {
    private int animationDuration = 300, nextColumns;
    private boolean animating = false, waitingScroll, shouldWait = true;
    private GridViewAnimationListener animationListener;
    public GridViewAnimated(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public GridViewAnimated(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public GridViewAnimated(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    @TargetApi(21)
    public GridViewAnimated(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }
    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
        return super.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
    }
    private void init() {
        this.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
    }
    public void setAnimating(boolean animating) {
        this.animating = animating;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        if (waitingScroll) {
            super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
            if (computeVerticalScrollOffset() == 0) {
                setEnabled(true);
                waitingScroll = false;
                setAnimating(false);
                setNumColumns(nextColumns);
            }
        } else if (!animating) {
            super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }
    public int getAnimationDuration() {
        return animationDuration;
    }
    public void setAnimationDuration(int animationDuration) {
        this.animationDuration = animationDuration;
    }
    public interface GridViewAnimationListener {
        void onAnimationStart(Animator animator);
        void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator);
        void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator);
        void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator);
    }
    public GridViewAnimationListener getAnimationListener() {
        return animationListener;
    }
    public void setAnimationListener(GridViewAnimationListener animationListener) {this.animationListener = animationListener;}
    public void removeAt(int... positions) {
        ArrayList<MyInteger> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer pos : positions) {
            ints.add(new MyInteger(pos));
        }
        Collections.sort(ints);
        int lowest = 99999, highest = 0;
        for (MyInteger pos : ints) {
            lowest = lowest < pos.getValue() ? lowest : pos.getValue();
            highest = highest > pos.getValue() ? highest : pos.getValue();
        }

        if (lowest >= 0 && highest <= getChildCount()) {
            ViewsVO originalViews = getOriginalViews();
            for (MyInteger pos : ints) {
                getAdapter().removeAt(pos.getValue());
            }
            getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            animateChildViews(originalViews);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if (adapter instanceof GridViewAnimatedAdapter) {
            super.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Log.e("GridViewAnimated", "Adapter needs to be instance of GridViewAnimatedAdapter");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Adapter needs to be instance of GridViewAnimatedAdapter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public GridViewAnimatedAdapter getAdapter() {
        return (GridViewAnimatedAdapter) super.getAdapter();
    }
    @Override
    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        if (getAdapter() == null || !getAdapter().hasStableIds() || getChildCount() == 0) {
            super.setNumColumns(numColumns);
            setAnimating(false);
            return;
        } else if (animating) {
            return;
        }
        setAnimating(true);
        if (computeVerticalScrollOffset() > 0) {
            waitingScroll = true;
            setEnabled(false);
            smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            nextColumns = numColumns;
            return;
        }
        ViewsVO originalViews = getOriginalViews();
        super.setNumColumns(numColumns);
        getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        animateChildViews(originalViews);
    }
    private ViewsVO getOriginalViews() {
        ViewsVO originalViews = new ViewsVO();
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            originalViews.addView(getChildAt(i));
        }
        return originalViews;
    }
    private void animateChildViews(final ViewsVO originalViews) {
        final GridViewAnimated gridView = this;
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                gridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                ViewsVO newViews = new ViewsVO();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                    for (int i = 0, z = getChildCount() - 1; z >= 0; z--, i++) {
                        gridView.getChildAt(z).setTranslationZ(i);
                    }
                }
                boolean hasFirst = false;
                View firstView = null, lastView = null;
                float firstHeight = 0, lastHeight = 0;
                ViewsVO newViewsFirstTime = new ViewsVO();
                for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = getChildAt(i);
                    ViewVO nView = newViews.addView(view);
                    ViewVO oView = originalViews.getView(view.getId());
                    if (oView != null) {
                        view.setScaleX(getScaleX(oView, nView));
                        view.setScaleY(getScaleY(oView, nView));
                        view.setTranslationX(getTranslateX(oView, nView));
                        view.setTranslationY(getTranslateY(oView, nView));
                        if (!hasFirst) {
                            firstView = view;
                            firstHeight = oView.getHeight();
                            hasFirst = true;
                        }
                        lastView = view;
                        lastHeight = oView.getHeight();
                        animateView(view);
                    } else {
                        newViewsFirstTime.addView(nView);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < newViewsFirstTime.size(); i++) {
                    try {
                        View view = newViewsFirstTime.getViews().get(i).getView();
                        view.getId();
                        view.setScaleX(view.getId() > firstView.getId() ? firstView.getScaleX() : lastView.getScaleX());
                        view.setScaleY(view.getId() > firstView.getId() ? firstView.getScaleY() : lastView.getScaleX());
                        view.setTranslationX(view.getId() > firstView.getId() ? firstView.getTranslationX() : lastView.getTranslationX());
                        view.setTranslationY(view.getId() > firstView.getId() ? 0 - firstHeight : lastView.getTranslationY() + lastHeight);
                        animateView(view);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private void animateView(final View view) {
        ViewPropertyAnimator animator = view.animate().setDuration(animationDuration).translationX(0).translationY(0).scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {animationListener.onAnimationStart(animator);}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                setAnimating(false);
                animationListener.onAnimationEnd(animator);
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {animationListener.onAnimationCancel(animator);}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {animationListener.onAnimationRepeat(animator);}
        });
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            animator.translationZ(0);
        }
    }
    private float getTranslateX(ViewVO ov, ViewVO nv) {return ov.getPosX() - nv.getPosX() - ((ov.getWidth() < nv.getWidth() ? nv.getWidth() - ov.getWidth() : ov.getWidth() - nv.getWidth()) * (ov.getWidth() < nv.getWidth() ? 0.5f : -0.5f));}
    private float getTranslateY(ViewVO ov, ViewVO nv) {return ov.getPosY() - nv.getPosY() - ((ov.getHeight() < nv.getHeight() ? nv.getHeight() - ov.getHeight() : ov.getHeight() - nv.getHeight()) * (ov.getHeight() < nv.getHeight() ? 0.5f : -0.5f));}
    private float getScaleY(ViewVO ov, ViewVO nv) {
        return ov.getHeight() / nv.getHeight();
    }
    private float getScaleX(ViewVO ov, ViewVO nv) {
        return ov.getWidth() / nv.getWidth();
    }
    private class ViewsVO {
        private ArrayList<ViewVO> views;
        private int size() {
            return views.size();
        }
        private ViewsVO() {
            views = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        private ViewVO addView(View view) {
            ViewVO v = new ViewVO(view);
            addView(v);
            return v;
        }
        private void addView(ViewVO view) {
            views.add(view);
        }
        private ViewVO getView(long id) {
            for (ViewVO view : views) {
                if (view.getId() == id) {
                    return view;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        private ArrayList<ViewVO> getViews() {
            return views;
        }
    }
    private class ViewVO {
        private View view;
        private int id;
        private float posY;
        private float posX;
        private float width;
        private float height;
        private ViewVO(View view) {
            this.view = view;
            id = view.getId();
            posX = view.getLeft();
            posY = view.getTop();
            width = view.getWidth();
            height = view.getHeight();
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public View getView() {
            return view;
        }
        private float getWidth() {
            return width;
        }
        private float getHeight() {
            return height;
        }
        private float getPosY() {
            return posY;
        }
        private float getPosX() {
            return posX;
        }
    }
    public static class GridViewAnimatedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private List objects;
        public GridViewAnimatedAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.objects = objects;
        }
        public void removeAt(int pos) {objects.remove(pos);}
        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
        public View dealViewToAnimation(View view) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            return view;
        }
    }
    private class MyInteger implements Comparable<MyInteger> {
        private int value;
        public MyInteger(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyInteger another) {return value > another.getValue() ? -1 : (value == another.getValue() ? 0 : 1);}}
}
```

And to use it is quite simple,
The adapter of GridView needs to extends GridViewAnimatedAdapter and:
getView(): To set an ID to each view and in the end of the method getView, needs to finish using the method dealViewToAnimation(View view) Ex:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    view.setId(images.getId());
    ...
    return dealViewToAnimation(view);
}
```

You can also set a listener to animation status:

```
gridView.setAnimationListener(new GridViewAnimated.GridViewAnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        mListMenu.setVisible(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
        mListMenu.setVisible(true);
        gridView.setAnimating(false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
    }
});
```

With this GridView you can animate changes in column number and animate removal of itens...

Animating change of column number:

```
gridView.setNumColumns(5);
```

Animating removal of itens:

```
gridView.removeAt(2, 7, 4);
gridView.removeAt(2);
```

When more than one, doesn't matter the order, the method will check the order and remove from the highest to lowest, considering that the highest id (that image added to the view) is the first view...

But despite it doesn't have the scale proportion animation like in the GridViewAnimated, it's better with RecyclerView, GridLayoutManager and DefaultItemAnimator, since it changes columns number and doesn't scroll...

```
GridLayoutmanager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

And then when you need to change the columns:

```
gridLayoutManager.requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout();        
gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(newNumberOfColumns);
```